# Why won't my kv BoxLayout centre horizontally?

Tags: python, kivy

This is my test.kv file:

```
BoxLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: None, None
        height: '160sp'
        width: '380sp'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'UserName'
            TextInput:
                id: user_name
                text: ''
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'Password'
            TextInput:
                id: password
                password: True
                text: ''
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'Domain'
            TextInput:
                id: domain
                text: 'howefarmingco.local'
        Button:
            text: 'Login'
            size_hints: None, 1
            width: .6
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
            on_press: app.do_login()
```

The idea is to have the login fields appear centred both vertically and horizontally. The vertical works as I expect it to, but the fields and button all display on the left edge of the window instead of the middle.

Am I missing something very basic here or just going about it in entirely the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

`pos_hint` is not used by all layouts!

From `FloatLayout` docs: `FloatLayout` honors the `pos_hint` and the `size_hint` properties of its children.

Changed my test.kv file so outer `BoxLayout` is now a `FloatLayout` and everything works as expected.